# What is causing that white border right after the outermost outline?

Tags: python, html, css, border, plotly-dash

got something that is driving me crazy here, please help me!

I've coded some website layout test with Dash in Python and here is code:

```
app = dash.Dash()

    app.layout = html.Div([
                           html.H2(children="Title",
                           style={'color':'lightgrey',
                                  'background-color': 'black',
                                  'margin-top': '0px',
                                  'margin-bottom': '0px',
                                  'padding-top':'12.5px',
                                  'padding-bottom':'12.5px',
                                  'padding-left':'10px',
                                  'text-align': 'center'}),
                          
                           html.Div(children=[],
    
                                    style={'widh':'50%', 
                                           'height':'50%',
                                           'border': '10px solid rgb(190, 190, 190)',
                                           'outline': '10px solid rgb(200, 255, 255)',
                                           'margin': '10px 10px 0px 10px',
                                           'padding':'0px 0px 0px 0px',
                                           'background-color': 'green',
                                           'background-size': 'auto'} )],
    
    style = {'widh':'100vw', 
             'height':'100vh',
             'border': '10px solid rgb(255, 255, 255)',
             'outline': '10px solid rgb(200, 200, 255)',
             'outline-offset': '0px',
             'margin': '0px 0px 0px 0px',
             'padding':'0px 0px 0px 0px',
             'background-color': 'lightblue',
             'background-size': 'auto'} 
    )
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug = True)
```

This gives me this layout (don't care about colors, its just structure test ^^):
[Coded layout result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42miB.png)

I have two questions about this:

The main one is: Why is that white border there?
The second is: What is causing the size os the page to have some extra space at the bottom? (See the reference below:)

[Second question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7PVu.png)

Comment: Extra spacing is probably caused because of ```box-sizing``` model. Set all to ```border-box``` to see if you can get rid of that spacing. Not sure which white border you are referring to in your first question.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help intentions man, but it seems that was not the origin of the issue. Someone answered it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, it's a weird but must-follow Dash rule/quirk that all CSS style parameters do **not** contain hyphens, and instead, you remove the hyphen and then capitalize the next word. So your code should be like this:

```py
import dash
import dash_daq as daq

from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash import no_update

from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2(
            children="Title",
            style={
                "color": "lightgrey",
                "backgroundColor": "black",
                "marginTop": "0px",
                "marginBottom": "0px",
                "paddingTop": "12.5px",
                "paddingBottom": "12.5px",
                "paddingLeft": "10px",
                "textAlign": "center",
            },
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[],
            style={
                "widh": "50%",
                "height": "50%",
                "border": "10px solid rgb(190, 190, 190)",
                "outline": "10px solid rgb(200, 255, 255)",
                "margin": "10px 10px 0px 10px",
                "padding": "0px 0px 0px 0px",
                "backgroundColor": "green",
                "backgroundSize": "auto",
            },
        ),
    ],
    style={
        "widh": "100vw",
        "height": "100vh",
        "border": "10px solid rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        "outline": "10px solid rgb(200, 200, 255)",
        "outlineOffset": "0px",
        "margin": "0px 0px 0px 0px",
        "padding": "0px 0px 0px 0px",
        "backgroundColor": "lightblue",
        "backgroundSize": "auto",
    },
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True)
```

You'll see the scrolling problem has gone away. As to the white border, you've styled that yourself with `"border": "10px solid rgb(255, 255, 255)"`! Does this answer your questions?

You can use chrome DevTools to inspect elements directly (super helpful must-know tool), as you can see:
[image: chrome devtools screenshot]

and that white border could easily be removed by simply eliminating it from your code, which you can preview as well in chrome DevTools by unchecking its box in the style panel, like this:

[image: white border removed]

Comment: Omg... I'm going to test it right now! Wait a minute.

Comment: Haha awesome! Yeah Chrome DevTools is super helpful for testing out CSS and also your whole layout for that matter. There's a really help reactjs chrome extension too, which makes the devtools even more helpful. I just upvoted your question, so I think you should have enough rep now to upvote my answer too if you don't mind  ☮️ ✌️

Comment: Thank you so much John! I am now feeling relieved and stupid at the same time for not seeing that I've put that white border there myself hahaha.